# How to define a global char matrix?

Tags: c

I'm defining a char matrix containing the description of the content of another matrix; this matrix ought to be global. In one of my header I wrote the following:

```
char descr[6][20];

descr[0][] = "name0";
descr[1][] = "name1";
descr[2][] = "name2";
descr[3][] = "name3";
descr[4][] = "name4";
descr[5][] = "name5";
```

when compiling I get the following error:

```
../../include/header1.h:56:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
     descr[0][] = "name0";
../../include/header1.h:56:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘descr’ [-Wimplicit-int]
../../include/header1.h:56:1: warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array ‘descr’ [-Wpedantic]
../../include/header1.h:56:1: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘int[]’
```

What's the problem? I'm using c89

Comment: Use `strcpy` to copy strings. `strcpy(descr[0], "name0");` And this is certainly should not be in a header.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to *initialize* your `descr`

```
char descr[6][20] = {
    "name0",
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3",
    "name4",
    "name5", /* you may leave the last comma out */
};
```

This initialization **not** (usually) go into a header file.

If you don't want to initialize and prefer later assignments (like in your original code) use `strcpy`.

```
char descr[6][20];
strcpy(descr[0], "name0");
/* ... */
```

Again, this code is **not** meant for a header file.

Comment: Why can't I put it in a header? In my mind putting in a header would make it global for all different modules given that the header is included

Comment: Put `extern char descr[6][20];` in the header file. If you define the object in the header file, you will end up with *N* instances; one for each time that header file is included.